# Is it a good idea to transform a date feature containing values such as '2021-04-02' into numerical values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science

I have a data frame containing dates ranging from january 1st 2010 (in this form 2010-01-01) to 31st december 2014 (2014-12-31)
Is it a good idea to transform this data into numerical values by using this code or does it have a bad influence on my predictions ?

```html
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date']=df['date'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
```

Comment: Pardon my English. I modified the question

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do exactly, but what I often do is to get the number of seconds or milliseconds in the date (typically since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC but sometimes something else) and then subtract the numerical value of the first date (2010-01-01 here) so you have seconds or ms since the start. Then divide by 60, 3600, 86400, etc., to get units that make sense for your application. Followup questions should probably be directed to ds.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you Robert !

Comment: @Prune You may not wish to answer basic questions, but if you choose to do so, the exasperated tone isn't helpful to OP.